# UE5 crash when I click into quixel bridge

Tags: unreal-engine5, quixel-bridge

I cannot manage to open Bridge in UE5, it craches. I re-started the UE though.

[image: bug]

Answer (score 0):

I've found an [answer in UE](https://help.quixel.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4405489594769/comments/4410310657425) forum which solved my problem.

I've added two plugins

- Web Authentication Plugin
- Web Browser

Not sure if both are needed but it works.